# What does a type declaration in front of a function call mean

Tags: c++

I'm working with a rather large project and I came up on a statement, which I do not understand. It looks like this:

```
visitor::DFV< Outer > visitor( *this, this->graph(), this->store() );
```

I would give you more code but it's really huge and I can't really tell which parts are relevant to this. Interesting is, that I can't even find any function called `visitor` in the structure DFV or it's predecessors and neither does Eclipse. I'm pretty sure I don't get the meaning of this right and I'm unable to find any reference to this c++ syntax. Can anyone explain to me in general the meaning of statements like this?

```
Type<SomeClass> foo(x, y);
```

Comment: The second one defines an object named `foo` of type `Type<SomeClass`>, initialized with the constructor that takes two arguments, `x` and `y`.

Comment: Why are you working on 'a rather large project' without having a proper knowledge of the C++ syntax? I'd recommend you to read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) first

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful. I was overwhelmed with the code and all the template usages with which I'm not that familiar and I lost track of the basics. Even though I was thinking about it the whole afternoon I found the answer myself 5mins after I posted the question and started to hit my head at a keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a function call, but a variable definition, and the `(...)` is the constructor parameter list.

Would it be more clear as

```
typedef visitor::DFV< Outer > Type;

//...
Type visitor(*this, this->graph(), this->store());
```

or

```
Type visitor(x, y, z);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your generic example of:

```
Type<SomeClass> foo(x, y);
```

It's a variable definition, where `Type<SomeClass>` is the type of the variable, `foo` is its name and the rest are the parameters passed to the class' constructor.

The class template `Type` will have some constructor, found in its definition (usually in its header file) which looks like:

```
template< typename T >
class Type
{
public:
    Type( int x, int y );
};
```

Comment: Worth adding that the scope `visitor::` might refer to a either class or namespace called `visitor`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really understand C++ very well if you don't get this syntax.

```
visitor::DFV< Outer > visitor( *this, this->graph(), this->store() );
```

I would interpret this as a function either a static function in the class visitor or a global function in the namespace visitor, thats all I can say with the code available. The `<Outer>` part is the template argument of the function for example if I did a template like this

```
template<class T> 
int someFunc<T>(T i, Tx)
{
    //whatever operations in the function
}
```

Then when I want to call that function I just do this

```
int i = someFunc<int>(2, 3);
//alternatively
int x = someFunc<std::string>("Hello", "World");
```

`*this` is a derefenced pointer to the class that is calling the function, `this->graph()` is the return value of the method `graph()` in the class thats calling this function, `this->store()` is the same as graph but with the return value of `store()`.

The second bit is instantiating a template class like this

```
template<class T>
class Type
{
public:
    Type(T x, T y);
};
```

Comment: "I would interpret this as a function either a static function in the class visitor or a global function in the namespace visitor, thats all I can say with the code available." it can't be either, what are you talking about?

Comment: How can't it be? if you call a function like this `foo::bar()` that could be a function called bar in a namespace called foo or a static function in a class called foo. I don't see what is not to get?

Comment: Yes, but you can't call a function *and* declare its type in the same statement.